# Can't extend/resize partition on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, redhat-enterprise-linux, oracle-linux

I've been struggling to extend the `sda3` partition shown below to the max available on `sda` which is `100G`. I wasn't aware my distro was Oracle Linux & I was trying all the solutions available for RHEL from other sites.

```
[root@localname bin]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda2   8:2    0    8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0 38.4G  0 part /
└─sda1   8:1    0  200M  0 part /boot/efi
```

I can't however find anything yet & thought to seek community's help here directly. Can someone help me out here in extending the partition `sda3` to the maximum capacity what `sda` actually holds?

**Fdisk Output:**

```
[root@localname bin]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1    97677311    48838655+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

FDISK done separately on each device gives the relevant info, but fdisk as a whole will only show the first partition details as mentioned above.

```
[root@localname bin]# fdisk -l /dev/sda2

Disk /dev/sda2: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes

[root@localname bin]# fdisk -l /dev/sda3

Disk /dev/sda3: 41.2 GB, 41209036800 bytes, 80486400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes
```

Additional Info: I only have access to CLI on the server, I don't have a UI access.

Comment: Most likely a dup of this: https://superuser.com/questions/1658719/resize-disk-lun-in-virtualbox-not-reflects-in-os-linux-suse/1658734#1658734 (What's worse is, either the version of fdisk / util-linux in your distro / installation does not support GPT yet, or your GPT is somewhat broken.)

Comment: Or, your `sda3` is not the last partition in terms of LBA, but merely entry number (i.e. between the unallocated space and it, there's `sda1`).